# Defining a relationship between a country and a recipe with Schema

Tags: semantic-web, schema.org, linked-data

I am building a web page that lists typical dishes for each individual country. Each dish is put in its own `article` and all of that goes fine. But I wonder if there is a way to link the `Recipe`s to the country. Does it make sense to also specify the country with http://schema.org/Country, and if so how can I link that to the dishes?

I thought about defining the main as a country, and then using http://schema.org/additionalProperty but that doesn't seem to make sense as it expects a PropertyValue, which the recipes aren't.

```
<main>
  <h1>France</h1>
  <p>
    <span class="capital" title="Capital">Paris</span>
    <span class="member-since" title="Member of the EU since 1958">1958</span>
  </p>

  <article id="recipe-1" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
    <h1>Éclairs</h1>
    <!-- A lot of recipe-related stuff -->
  </article>

  <article id="recipe-2" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
    <h1>Macaron</h1>
    <!-- A lot of recipe-related stuff -->
  </article>

  <article id="recipe-3" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
    <h1>Tarte Tatin</h1>
    <!-- A lot of recipe-related stuff -->
  </article>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the cuisine of a [`Recipe`](http://schema.org/Recipe) with its [`recipeCuisine`](http://schema.org/recipeCuisine) property:

> The cuisine of the recipe (for example, French or Ethiopian).

It expects a `Text` value.

There is also the [`locationCreated`](http://schema.org/locationCreated) property, which expects a `Place` value (which includes `Country`), but it might be a stretch to use it in this context. Also it wouldn’t be clear if it refers to the location where the recipe is originally coming from, or to the location where the written form was created.

Schema.org doesn’t seem to offer a property to connect a `Country` and `Recipe` directly. But you could still connect the items via `WebPage`.
So for example, if you say `WebPage about Country` and `WebPage mainEntity ItemList`, and have each `Recipe` as `itemListElement`, there is at least some connection (a page about a specific country has a list of recipes as main content = the recipes are probably related to that country).

Comment: @BramVanroy: The semantic HTML doesn’t affect the parsed Microdata, so it’s a separate topic. The `main` element would include, well, the main content of the page (i.e., everything that is not repeated on other similar pages). And as the page seems to about a country and its recipes (and maybe more stuff), all this should be part of `main`. -- You could use `Country` and provide it e.g. as `about` value for the `WebPage` item.

Comment: @BramVanroy: Yes, Schema.org seems to lack a property to connect these directly. But you can still connect the items via `WebPage`. So for example, if you say `WebPage about Country` and `WebPage mainEntity ItemList`, and have each recipe as `itemListElement`, there is some connection (a page about a specific country has a list of recipes as main content = the recipes are probably related to that country).

Comment: @BramVanroy: I did. Alternatives could be: a) finding a suitable property in another vocabulary, b) suggesting that Schema.org adds a suitable property (if you think it’s a common/useful case), c) using `recipeCuisine` with a `Country` value (not expected, but technically allowed; but I’m not sure if a country makes sense as cuisine, i.e., "France" instead of "French).

Comment: I might suggest that recipeCuisine be removed and instead `recipeOrigin` (or similar) is introduced, which could be any `Place`. This way you can talk about an 'Asian kitchen' as well as a 'Diesterst beer' (my Belgian home city). In other words, you have a much larger scale.