# Why does my Recipe need a url?

Tags: url, schema.org, linked-data

I am testing my Schema with Google's Rich Text tool<sup>1</sup>, and it keeps telling me that my `Recipe` item needs a `url` property.

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/prototype) states:

> Errors indicate either missing required fields or syntax errors.

The error that I get is that the field `url` is empty and shouldn't be. However, I have no idea what I should fill in. I mean, obviously the tool expects a URL, but - semantically - whereto should that URL go? What if I don't have a URL to point to?

If I decide to leave the supposedly required field empty, does that mean that the complete `Recipe` will not be a valid Schema? Or simply that it's missing a field?

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <main>
        <header itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Country" itemprop="about">
            <h1 itemprop="name">France</h1>
            <p>
                <span class="capital" title="Capital" itemprop="containsPlace">Paris</span>
                <span title="Member of the EU since 1958" itemprop="additionalProperty" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
                    <meta itemprop="name" content="Member of the EU since">
                    <span itemprop="value" class="member-since">1958</span>
                </span>
            </p>
        </header>
        <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
            <meta itemprop="description" content="Recipes that are particular for France">
            <article class="recipe loading" id="recipe-1" data-recipe="" itemref="img-0" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
                <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
                <aside class="media">
                    <img itemprop="image" id="img-0" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ef/4c/5c/ef4c5c0b008d11710caa7a10f502d288.jpg">
                    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject" class="youtube">
                        <a itemprop="contentUrl" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHgULHwyZJo" title="Watch a video on how to make Eclair">
                            <meta itemprop="name" content="Making éclairs">
                            <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2016-07-12">
                            <meta itemprop="description" content="In this video you'll learn how to make éclairs">
                            <img itemprop="thumbnailUrl" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fHgULHwyZJo/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Eclairs tutorial">
                        </a>
                        <iframe href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHgULHwyZJo" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fHgULHwyZJo?enablejsapi=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showInfo=0&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&amp;widgetid=1"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </aside>
                <div class="text">
                    <div class="wiki-text">
                        <h1 itemprop="name">Eclairs</h1>
                        <p itemprop="description">An éclair is an oblong pastry made with choux dough filled with a cream and topped with icing. The dough, which is the same as that used for profiterole, is typically piped into an oblong shape with a pastry bag and baked until it is crisp and hollow
                            inside. </p>
                        <p class="read-more">For more information about <span class="recipe-name">Éclair</span>, read the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89clair" title="Wikipedia page about %C3%89clair" itemprop="sameAs">Wiki</a>.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rating" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
                        Rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">3.5</span>/5 based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">11</span> customer reviews
                    </div>
                    <div class="cooking">
                        <h2>Bake it yourself!</h2>
                        <div>
                            <meta itemprop="cookTime" content="PT50M">
                            <span>Bake time: 50 minutes</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Related question: [Defining a relationship between a country and a recipe with Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878609/defining-a-relationship-between-a-country-and-a-recipe-with-schema)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shown in Google’s SDTT doesn’t mean that you have an actual error in your Schema.org markup (as *not* providing the `url` property is perfectly fine). It’s checking if your markup conforms to Google’s guidelines for their [Recipes](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/recipes) rich card. If you don’t care about it, you don’t have to do anything.

If you care about the Recipes rich card:

Google requires the `url` property for each `ListItem` (i.e., each `Recipe`) in a [list of recipes](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/recipes#itemlist-properties):

> `ListItem.url`
>   URL, **required**
>
> The canonical URL of the item page. Every item should have a unique URL.

While you could achieve "unique URL[s]" with fragments (like `#recipe-2`, `#recipe-3` etc.), the guideline says "item page", so Google seems to want to see a dedicated page per recipe.

However, their more general [Mark Up Your Lists](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings) documentation describes the "Combined" way to mark up host-specific lists, which allows this (bold emphasis mine):

> When multiple recipes are on a single page, use list page markup that both itemizes the data types and exposes their properties in the item field.
>
> In this case, be sure to include a unique URL for each item, which **in this case might include an anchor tag**.

So if this also applies to their Recipes rich card, it might work in your case to provide the fragment as URL:

```html
<article id="recipe-1" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe http://schema.org/ListItem">
  <link itemprop="url" href="#recipe-1" />
  <!-- … -->
</article>

<article id="recipe-2" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe http://schema.org/ListItem">
  <link itemprop="url" href="#recipe-2" />
  <!-- … -->
</article>
```

Comment: Interesting. Currently I am using a URL with query parameters (e.g. `/?country=FR&recipe=Macaron`). With JavaScript I bring the correct recipe into view, similar to how an anchor tag does. I wonder if this works fine for Google as well. I know they used to prefer hash bangs, but in 2015 they stepped away from this idea as "Their crawlers can read a website as does a browser." I don't exactly *need* Google's Recipe cards, so that's fine. I do wonder, though, does Schema.org **require** any properties for items? In the documentation I haven't seen a distinction between required and optional.

Comment: @BramVanroy: Schema.org never requires any property, so these "missing property" errors in Google’s SDTT are always about one of their own search result features.

Answer (score 2):

The URL parameter should contain the base web address at which your item can be viewed using a browser.

This parameter is of great importance in indexing your content by smart content tools and search bots, like Google. Once you provide it, Google will be able to link any reference to your item to the declared URL.

This param is important when your web-app serves the same content at different addresses for different devices. By providing the same URL parameter, you can avoid any eventual penalty for duplicated content.

The URL parameter is usually the base (un-prettified) version of your permalinks, especially when using popular website engines like WordPress, where you can change your permalinks structure, but the base url scheme (usually in the form of `/?p=id` - where `id` is the id of the article) will always work. This way you can make sure that, even if you decide to change the permalinks structure after a while, your ranking and indexing for that content will not be hurt, because the declared URL will remain unchanged and older links to it will work, regardless of your pretty-permalinks current scheme.

Declared URL parameter also avoids another common problem for indexing services:

For example, if you provide a link for your monthly featured recipe, if the search engine indexes the current recipe with the "this months hot recipe link", when people will be looking for it (based on the indexed text or ingredients) next month, they'll find another recipe, which would not be what they are looking for, so *they will hit the back button* snappish, thus:

- not finding what they were looking for, although it is on your website and
- hurting your ranking, because Google monitors user behavior and whenever they go back, it clearly means the currently indexed content is wrong for that search.

Providing a URL for the recipe will allow the search engine to index and link it correctly so people who want to see it can see it and so that your ranking goes up while they spend time on your website reading the recipe or when bookmarking it.

Comment: Hm, so I added the url parameter with a meta tag inside the article, giving it a value like so: `/?country=BE&recipe=Waffles`, and I tried an absolute url as well, but the Google tool gives another error, namely 'All given values for th eurl property have to contain the same domain'. Do you have any idea what they mean? I tried this with multiple Recipes on a page as well as only one, but the error persists.

Comment: Apparently this is a well known "bug" with google's tool.